# insmod: ERROR: could not insert module module.ko: Invalid parameters

Tags: linux

I tried to build my own kernel module and insert it to the linux kernel.
However, when I do "sudo insmod module.ko", it returns with the error:

"insmod: ERROR: could not insert module module.ko: Invalid parameters"

the following is my code "module.c" and Makefile

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>

static int __init hello_init(void)
{
     printk("Hello world/n");
    return 0;
}

 static void __exit hello_exit(void)
{
    printk("Bye Corne/n");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Makefile:

```
obj-m:=module.o

CURRENT_PATH :=$(shell pwd)
VERSION_NUM :=$(shell uname -r)
LINUX_PATH ?=/lib/modules/$(VERSION_NUM)/build

all :
    make -C $(LINUX_PATH) M=$(CURRENT_PATH) modules
clean :
    make -C $(LINUX_PATH) M=$(CURRENT_PATH) clean

export ARCH=x86
```

Answer (score 1):

I have replaced `Makefile` and compiled your module in kernel version `3.13.0-24`(Ubuntu-14.04). It's successfully loaded.

My Makefile code:

```
obj-m += module.o

all:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```